# Vscode extension to highlight any css errors in React.js

Tags: css, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I have this line of code in React.js

```
<button style={{ fontsize: '50px', width: '60px', height: '60px' }}>
```

It't not detecting the error fontsize should be fontSize. Is there any extension that would detect this error?

Comment: It's called [TypeScript](https://typescriptlang.org/). You should get started with it. It's pretty darn useful in other places as well.

Comment: Did you set up [a jsconfig.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) yet?

Comment: You might want to set up linting rules as part of your project—e.g. `eslint`, `prettier`, etc—as well as their VSCode integration.